# Trying to link different Functions with different $var's

Tags: php

Hi i'm pretty new to programming and I wanted to know how to link different Functions/Methods with different $var's.

My current code is

```
<?php 

class wasd {

    function som($pX, $pY=8)    
    {
        return $pX+$pY; 
    }   
}
{ 

    function som($pX, $pY=8)    
    {
        return $pX+$pY; 
    }   

}
{

    function test($pX, $pY=4)    
    {
        return $pX+$pY; 
    }   
 
}

  $oSom1 = new wasd();
  $var1 = $oSom1->som(11);

  $oSom2 = new wasd();
  $var2 = $oSom2->som(5);

  $oSom3 = new wasd();
  $var3 = $oSom3->som(5);
  ?>

  <body>
    <?php echo $var1; ?>
    <?php echo $var2; ?>
    <?php echo $var3; ?>
  </body>
```

My problem is that if I try to edit the 5 from `$var2 = $oSom2->som(5);` nothing happens because i'm doing it wrong. The same for `$var3 = $oSom3->som(5);`. It only changes when I edit `$var1`

Comment: What does the `som` function do? What is the `$var1` relation?

Comment: My code isn't even placed, I cant place the whole code for some reason. I use Control + K but it doesn't work

Comment: Might be too long, how many lines are you trying to add?

Comment: Https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting can help you with displaying things in your question

Comment: Hi, my codes are placed now. Can u review the thread again?

Comment: In PHP, putting regular code blocks inside `{}` is not invalid but it doesn't serve any purpose. I have no idea of what your doubt is but you're probably confusing [functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php) with [class methods](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php).

Comment: One `som()` is part of a class, the second is a global function.. curly braces define a new scope. But he's always calling the class method...

Comment: @LarsStegelitz No, it doesn't define a new scope. PHP does not feature block scopes.

Comment: our task was to use 1 class for different functions so I can't make a new wasd class. But its already fixed. Still thank you tho :D

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: kk will do that in a bit

Answer (score 1):

You should get basic lesson how classes are beginning and how they are ended. In your case you use too much braces, it should be shortened. Also double `som()` declaration should be removed.

```php
class wasd
{

    function som($pX, $pY = 8)
    {
        return $pX + $pY;
    }

    function test($pX, $pY = 4)
    {
        return $pX + $pY;
    }

}
```

#### bonus TIP

Although you starting it as OOP project (which is good in general) you doesn't always need to create an object. In case of methods that just doing some own capsulated logic like your simple math `som()` you can declare it as a [static method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php), hen instead of creating an object of `wasd` class many times, you can call this method directly in the code without object, like.

```
$var1 = wasd::som(11);
```

It's commonly called *utility methods*.

Comment: Okay thank you very much but i'm really new to this so I couldn't really know.

Comment: You need to know some basic rulez, otherwise you'll waste your own time. TIP: use some good IDE like PhpStorm with syntax highlighting and **code formatting** features. Proper code formatting helps to realize structure of your code easier, so it's easier to find mistakes.